# How do I use PHP to send users to specific pages based on where they are coming from

Tags: php, forwarding, referrer

What I want to do, is use PHP to forward users to specific pages based on where they are coming from on my site.(basically this is a next button functionality)

So what I'd like to do is have PHP check the referring url and then forward based on that value.

Something like this:(note I can't post multiple urls, so imagine that there is the http:// in front of all of them)

If url: mysite.com/gallery1/ then forward to: mysite.com/gallery2/

If url: mysite.com/gallery2/ then forward to: mysite.com/gallery3/

If url: mysite.com/gallery3/ then forward to: mysite.com/gallery4/

And if the referring url isn't on the list or they just typed in the php script url directly, send them to mysite.com/nogallery/

I'd like to use a database to store the data. Basically it'd have 2 columns. 1 for referrer url, and 1 for the forwarding url.

If you could help me out it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you know what to do already.  If you want to store the URLs in a database, that's fine, but just imagine you've got a structure like this:

```
<?PHP
$routes = array(
'example.com/1.php'=>'example.com/2.php',
'example.com/2.php'=>'example.com/3.php',
'example.com/3.php'=>'example.com/4.php');

if (array_key_exists($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$routes)){
    header('Location: http://'. $routes[$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']]);
}else{
    header('Location: http://example.com/default.php');
}
exit;

?>
```

Comment: I'd love to hardcode it, but I'll have a few thousand of these forwards eventually, wouldn't that make the script a little bit slow to load?

Comment: You could always compare times using a database versus a giant list in the PHP file.

Eventually, you'll cross the threshold where one is no longer faster than the other—just a matter of when.

Comment: True, for very large datasets a database would likely be faster (and perhaps easier to administer).  If you wanted to keep the map in a flat file, you could always try to sprinkle in some in-memory caching using memcache or apc, if they're available.

Comment: I think I'll just have separate files. Since this is just a "next" button for me, I'll just make a next2 file when it gets slow